# What is program point and what's the relationship with basic block?

Tags: compiler-optimization, dataflow, ssa

When I read the book "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools", I always meet the word "program point", though I got a blur feeling about what it is, and with this feeling, I went through the chapter about data flow analysis, I still want to know what a "program point" exactly is, and what's the relationship with a basic block?

Comment: What's the dragon book? wouldn't it be explained there?

Comment: @Steven, it is "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools", pretty famous nick name is compiler area. I have edit it to the real name any way.

Comment: Give an example of its use